# Wrong integer output on Console.Read()

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to output a variable that I'm getting as an input from the user, but I get the wrong number.

Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sequence
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int userInput = Console.Read();

            Console.WriteLine("User input is: {0}", userInput.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("User input is: {0}", userInput);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3
User input type is: System.Int32
User input is: 51
Press any key to continue
```

If I type 4, I get 52. 5, 53 and so on.

Comment: They are ascii codes. Read `Console.Read` documentation.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume the reason is because reading the documentation for `Console.Read` would have cleared this up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Console.ReadLine()` which returns string and you need to convert into `int`

Try this

```
namespace sequence
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            int userInput;
            if (!int.TryParse(input, out userInput))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered invalid number");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User input is: {0}", userInput.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("User input is: {0}", userInput);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Returning from `Main` will exit the application. It is improbable that the user will be able to read the validation message.

Comment: @Gusdor Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `Console.Read()` returns the integer code of the character being read. You must subtract 48 from the char to get the actual number.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sequence
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int userInput = Console.Read();

            Console.WriteLine("User input is: {0}", userInput.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("User input is: {0}", userInput - 48);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you do if the user enters the character `A` (ascii 65)? Is 17 an appropriate output?

Comment: Read the question : Wrong integer output on Console.Read()

I assume that he is interested in integers.

Comment: That's one way of looking at it. Is there any reason that `int.TryParse` isn't good enough?

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't good enough. It solves a bigger problem. My solution is focused on solving the particular case of the author.