# Cannot calculate Long Data type in C#

Tags: c#, long-integer

I do not know why am I getting output as 0. Please help me to figure out my mistake in correcting the calculation for the long data type in C#. I have almost all variables in long to make it easier, but even then, the code does not work as expected.

```
        long data_user;
        long GB;
        long MB;
        long kB;
        long bits;
        long bits_rem;
        double giga_C;
        double mega_c;
        double kilo_C;
        double byte_C;
        double sub_tot;

        Console.Write("\nEnter the number of bytes used: ");
        data_used = Console.Read();

        //Divide data into each units.
        GB = data_user / 1073741824; 
        giga_C = Convert.ToDouble(15.00 * GB);

        MB = bits_rem / 1045214;
        mega_C = (6.05 * MB);                  

        kB = bits_rem / 10002;
        kilo_C = (3.50 * kB);  

        bits = bits_rem / 0.1;
        bits_C = (0.01 * bits);                     

        sub_tot = (giga_C + mega_C + kilo_C + byte_C);
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Why division is always ZERO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278585/why-division-is-always-zero), [Division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9288904/8967612), and [Wrong integer output on Console.Read()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32050026/8967612).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/10851273/1070452 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/661028/1070452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Console.Read` reads the next character from the Console, so that you always get smaller number divided by big one (which is zero in **integer** arithmetic). For example, you write `1234`, but `Console.Read` returns `49` because Unicode point for `'1'` is `49`. Then you try to divide `49` by `1073741824` and obviously get `0`.

You need to read your value as following `Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine())`